# Android RSS reader description data fetching error

Tags: android, html, textview, rss-reader

I am developing an android rss reader but the problem i am facing is when trying to fetch data from rss feeds where description contain html content like the following:

```
<item>
    <title>Katima&#45;Comic</title>
    <link>http://thelinknewspaper.ca/article/3063</link>

    <guid isPermaLink="false">thelink_entry_3063</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[


        <img alt=""  width="690" height="407" src="http://thelinknewspaper.ca/images/cache/c11f5084728aa602d09cd15bb20ae7a86b06be79.jpg" />
    </p>


    <p>This is the story of Andrew Murchison, a Katimavik volunteer whose life was changed by the federal youth program.</p>        
    <p><iframe class="scribd_iframe_embed" src="http://www.scribd.com/embeds/101595075/content?start_page=1&view_mode=list&access_key=key-1ss1qrvm5hi9h7othhkq" data-auto-height="true" data-aspect-ratio="0.777636594663278" scrolling="no" id="doc_79691" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>




            ]]></description>
            <dc:creator>Paku Daoust&#45;Cloutier</dc:creator>
    <dc:date>2012-07-31T00:20:54+00:00</dc:date>
</item>
```

I am displaying the content in a textview which displays the content as is with the html tags!

How can i display it in a good readable way with a scroll bar inside a specific area

thanks

here's a portion of the code i am using:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
            return view;

        objBean = items.get(position);


        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdesc);



        if (holder.title != null && null != objBean.getTitle()
                && objBean.getTitle().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getTitle()));
        }
        if (holder.description != null && null != objBean.getDescription()
                && objBean.getDescription().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.description.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getDescription()));
        }


        // Even and odd Row...
        if ((position % 2) == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_even);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_list_odd);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

and

```
public class NewsDetail extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        String title = b.getString("title");
        String desc = b.getString("description");

        final String link = b.getString("link");


        TextView tvtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        TextView tvdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);


        Button btnWeb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngotolink);
        btnWeb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link)));
            }
        });

        tvtitle.setText(title);
        tvdesc.setText(desc);


        setTitle(title);
    }

}
```

Thank again any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the text, set it as text from html:

```
tvdesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
```

If you want to show images from the html you'll need to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) with something along these lines:

```
myWebview.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Great thanks this solved to remove the HTML tags from appearing, but what about the images inside the description? can a "textview" show an image or i should use something other than the "textview" element to display the feed content? Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer above to answer your questions.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I will try your suggestion for the webview and get back with results. Do you know the "pulse" application? I want to display the article in a similar way to show the links and media such as images and videos, are they using webview as you suggested? Thank you

Comment: They are most likely parsing out the image tag as well as removing any html then just displaying the image in an image view and the text in a text view.  Its hard to say for sure since I havent seen their source code :)